# Python printing different values

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

in my project i must print different value every three minutes. These values are stored in a dictionary. And then in array.

Array is Like this:

```py
import dictionary # my own dictionary

array = ["n1", "n2"]

array[0] = dictionary.dict["website1"]
array[1] = dictionary.dict["website2"]
```

It must print array indexes every 3 minute. Like this:

First three minute: array[0]

Second three minute: array[1]

Comment: As in, you need a timer to output the next value after 3 minutes, or at any time you want to get *a* value from the dict, and that should be constant for 3 minutes, then change?

Comment: I don't quite get your question. Are you looking to implement a timer-like object or what?

Comment: @deceze yes how can i do it?

Comment: Please use poper terms because you might confuse others. `["n1", "n2"]` is not an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) just because you call the variable `array`. It's a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list).

Comment: *"Do you want A or B?"* - *"Yes."* — Genius!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop in combination with the `time.sleep` function [(official documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep).

```py
import time
for arr in array:
  print(arr)
  time.sleep(3 * 60) # sleep takes a time in seconds
```